# Add Static data into tables by using core data

Tags: ios, core-data

I want to use core data in my project, I have more than 2 dozen tables and have many relationship with each other.

My requirement is to have static data added into these tables and also added random data on runtime.

So what I have learned so far that Core data is not database and I can't hold static data onto it because this is first time I am going to implement in proper project.

So what should I follow is there any approach where we can add static data onto it or should I go to use sqlite ?

Kindly suggest and guide me on this. Thanks.

Comment: do you need static values (records) in any of the core data table..?

Comment: yes, values can be more than 1k.

Comment: if you need few static records, then you can add programmatically when you invoke your application. are you having any xml file for 1k records.? if your are having then loop and create the records for entity. I am not sure whether we are having other approach to add records..

Answer (score 1):

You should write a simple CLI app, using Core Data, that imports that XML data into your SQLite file.  Then you can embed that SQLite file into the final application.

On launch, if the file does not exist in the documents directory you copy it out of the application bundle and put it into place.  This will enable you to include data with your application and have that static data in place when the user first runs your application and without forcing the user to wait for that data to be processed at run time.